# How to debug log messages on a window from different modules

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I show all the log messages on a single Window getting the messages from different modules and keep it running on the background?

This is my code so far …

Here I get all my log messages on a file.
my_logger.py

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class ConsoleWindowLogHandler(logging.Handler, QObject):
    LoggerSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        QObject.__init__(self)

        f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')

        fh = logging.FileHandler('logger.log')
        fh.setFormatter(f)

        logger.addHandler(fh)
        
    def emit(self, logRecord):
        message = str(logRecord.getMessage())
        self.LoggerSignal.emit(message)
```

In this module i can show messages emitted from this module only. I can't see messages emitted from other modules.
example1.py

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from my_logger import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        # set the title
        self.setWindowTitle("Debugger")
 
        # setting  the geometry of window
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        # Layout
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.btn_debbugger = QPushButton('Start Debugger')
        self.btn_clean_debbugger = QPushButton('Clean Debugger')
        self.lbl_debugger = QTextEdit('Debbuger')
            
        self.vertLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertLayout .addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.vertLayout .addWidget(self.btn_debbugger)
        self.vertLayout .addWidget(self.btn_clean_debbugger)
        self.setLayout(self.vertLayout )

        # Connect button
        self.btn_debbugger.clicked.connect(self.initialize_thread_1)
        self.btn_clean_debbugger.clicked.connect(self.CleanUi)

        # Thread
        self.thread_1 = Worker(self.myProcess, ())


        # Console handler
        consoleHandler = ConsoleWindowLogHandler()
        consoleHandler.LoggerSignal.connect(self.textEdit.append)
        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

        logger.info("Starting Debugger ...")


    def initialize_thread_1(self):
        
        if not self.thread_1.isRunning():
            self.thread_1.start()#start thread
            self.btn_debbugger.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            logger.info("thread_1 already running ...")

    def myProcess(self):
        for i in range(3):
            logger.error("Line %d" % i)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.btn_debbugger.setEnabled(True)

    def CleanUi(self):
        self.textEdit.clear()


class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self, func, args):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        self.func(*self.args)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

output from example1.py

Here am trying to send log messages to "example1.py".

external_module.py

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from example1 import Window
from my_logger import *


class ExternalWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExternalWindow, self).__init__()

        logger_instance = ConsoleWindowLogHandler()
        debugger_instance = Window()

        logger_instance.LoggerSignal.connect(self.debugger_instance.textEdit.append)
        logger.debug("Message from extermal module")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you show the output of logger.log and the QTextEdit when you run example1 and external_module.py?

Comment: @SargeATM I edited my post with the output, regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## QtWindowHandler

*qt_window_logger.py*

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class QtWindowHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, *args) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.window = Window()
        self.window.show()

    def emit(self, record):
        self.window.textEdit.append(self.format(record))


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        # set the title
        self.setWindowTitle("Debugger")
 
        # setting  the geometry of window
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        # Layout
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.btn_debbugger = QPushButton('Start Debugger')
        self.btn_clean_debbugger = QPushButton('Clean Debugger')
        self.lbl_debugger = QTextEdit('Debbuger')
            
        self.vertLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertLayout .addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.vertLayout .addWidget(self.btn_debbugger)
        self.vertLayout .addWidget(self.btn_clean_debbugger)
        self.setLayout(self.vertLayout )

        # Connect button
        self.btn_debbugger.clicked.connect(self.initialize_thread_1)
        self.btn_clean_debbugger.clicked.connect(self.CleanUi)
        


    def initialize_thread_1(self):
        logger.info("Starting Debugger ...")


    def CleanUi(self):
        self.textEdit.clear()
```

In ***main*** module

```
import logging
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from qt_window_logger import QtWindowHandler


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
    window_handler = QtWindowHandler()
    window_handler.setFormatter(f)
    logger.addHandler(window_handler)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.debug("test debug")
    logger.info("test info")
    logger.warning("test warn")
    app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    main()
```

##### SCREENSHOT

[image: final result]

Comment: I also changed this line "logger_instance.LoggerSignal.connect(debugger_instance.textEdit.append)" on external_module.py ... I can get the message on my log file (2022-08-21 23:26:30,041 - DEBUG - my_logger - Message from extermal module) but not on my QtextEdit.

Comment: This is the output adding the line logger.addHandler(logger_instance)  ... 
(2022-08-21 23:51:37,605 - INFO - my_logger - Starting Debugger ...
2022-08-21 23:51:37,605 - ERROR - my_logger - Line 0
2022-08-21 23:51:38,605 - ERROR - my_logger - Line 1
2022-08-21 23:51:39,427 - DEBUG - my_logger - Message from extermal module
2022-08-21 23:51:39,427 - DEBUG - my_logger - Message from extermal module
2022-08-21 23:51:39,607 - ERROR - my_logger - Line 2 ) .... 

still not showing the msg on the QtexEdit

Comment: @devxen21 What happens if you call logger_instance.emit(...) yourself?

Comment: Hi, logger_instance.emit(debugger_instance.textEdit.append)  ... shows this: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'getMessage'

Comment: Hi, following your example it shows this ... QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
Aborted  ... 
I have to do it after this "app = QApplication(sys.argv)", also if I don't instanciate this: debugger_instance = Window() ... I can't call my textEdit right? ... anyways i still can't print the log message.

Comment: @devxen21 I reimplemented solution from scratch using some of your code in places.

Comment: Uses PySide6 but should be compatible with PyQt5.

Comment: Hi, thanks it is working now! ... appreciate it!